# Meaning of a first-order logic theory

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm wondering what results are typically used to show that a first-order logic theory captures its intended meaning.

To make things concrete, suppose I have a signature $\Sigma = \{ 0, S, =, +, \leq \}$ and I define a theory T that tries to capture the expected meaning of these symbols (something like Peano's axioms). How to state formally it is indeed the case?

I'm thinking of something along these lines: "For all formulas $P$, we have $T \vDash_1 P$ if and only if $ \vDash_2  P$", where $\vDash_1$ is the usual entailment relation with the signature symbols uninterpreted, and $\vDash_2$ gives them their "meta-level" meaning. Is that correct?

Comment: If you succeed in defining a $\vDash_2$ that captures the _intended_ meaning specifically, Gödel's incompleteness theorem says that it's impossible for any first-order theory to reproduce that meaning exactly.

Comment: So what we actually do is make do with theories such that $\mathbb N\vDash P$ is (we strongly believe) a _necessary_ condition for $T\vDash P$, though it cannot become a _sufficient_ condition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm [..] for any recursively enumerable* first-order theory to reproduce [..]

Comment: @StefanMesken: Right.

Comment: See [categorical theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_categoricity_theorem) : "a theory is *categorical* if all of its models are isomorphic."

Comment: See also the post [Difference between completeness and categoricity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933466/difference-between-completeness-and-categoricity).

Comment: To the OP, of course the argument you want - even the bare claim you want to prove - has to be made either informally or in some other formal system which we are confident can reasonably describe "$\models_2$." Either response has obvious drawbacks but it's worth pointing out that the latter is not as silly as it may appear: there are lots of times, for example, that it's fruitful to reason about the true theory of $\mathbb{N}$ from within set theory (of course ZFC can't resolve every *question* about this theory - e.g., does it contain Con(ZFC)? - but it can prove many useful facts about it).

Comment: @NoahSchweber first comment: yes, as already observed by Stefan Mesken. (Unfortunately the original comment cannot now be edited with more careful phrasing).